# Reusing code (function?) in PHP

Tags: php

Got this bit of code:

```
if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"] == 0) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], "path/".$_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
    }
```

I would like to reuse it for more files being uploaded. Was thinking function with some params but it seems i can't get the vars correctly.

Ok fixed it like this:

```
function upload($file) {

        $allowedExts = array("pdf, jpg, gif, png");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES[$file]["name"]));

        if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) && ($_FILES[$file]["error"] == 0) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"], "img/new/".$_FILES[$file]["name"]);
        }
    }
```

And calling via:

```
upload("file1");
```

Not sure about the `$_FILES` loop...

Comment: Can we see the function you tried?

Comment: This is not something you should be reusing.  You're giving the user free reign over your entire file system.  Don't use this insecure code!

Comment: If I upload a file named `hax.php`, then I can access it and take over your site.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the $_FILES array and execute your code for each file, like this:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
    if ($file["error"] == 0) {
        move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], "path/".$file["name"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, got it! Quite elegant solution. Altho, are there any security implications? As i understand this would attempt to upload all files presented in the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: Ehh, well security implications are another story.  I'm answering the initial question (how to process all of the files in the array).  You should be including checks and validations to ensure that the user can only do what you want them to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
function upload_file($file, $upload_path)
{

    if($file["error"] == 0){

        $moved = move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $upload_path.$file["name"]);

        if($moved){

            return true;

        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

simple but works for your needs.

Comment: also you could loop through your upload field names and call this function in your loop - modified to work with Axels loop

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: [PHP File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

This works:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
        {            
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
            }
            else
            {               
                if(move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_dir.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
                {                    
                    $messages[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' uploaded';
                }
                else
                {                
                    $messages[] = 'Uploading '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' Failed';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**Note:** It's a good idea to validate the files using exif_imagetype(), getimagesize() and similar.. Every other value than `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['image']['error']` shouldn't be trusted. It takes whatever is sent from the browser and can easily be faked.